# string to hexa String increases length

Tags: c#

I have a string which contains special characters(as a result of encryption) that is to be saved in XML, which later has to be saved in DB(unfortunately we cannot change this logic). To avoid special character I am converting string to hexa and saving in XML. This works fine but the problem is the length increases 4 times when I convert to Hexa. This creates a problem when I later insert the string from XML to DB.

Is there any solution to convert string to hexa or something else and do not increase the current string length?

Comment: Why are the special characters a problem? You probably just need to escape them if they're reserved for XML. Anyway, you could convert the string to Base64 instead. It'll still increase the length but by a factor of ~1.3 instead of 4.

Comment: The "encryption" that resulted in such a string seems wrong.

Comment: you could simply escape the special chars and be done with it

Comment: Appreciate your response. I cannot escape special characters because I need to decrypt the string later.  As suggested above I will try with Base64 instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string with special characters that needs to be saved in XML, you should consider **escaping** the necessary special characters.

Since I can't see which string you are working with, I suggest you search for 'XML escaping characters'. There are enough resources on how to escape characters and some online tools that do it for you.

### Example:

Given an unescaped string without special characters such as:

```
abc&123>(#Ki
```

Would yield an escaped string like:

```
abc&amp;123&gt;(#Ki
```

Unfortunately, this will still increase the string size depending on how many characters have to be escaped, but I reckon a lot less than converting it to hexadecimal. I cannot think of any standard way you could maintain the same string length while converting any special characters, unfortunately.

If the length is an issue when inserting the string in the database, could you allow larger string lengths in the database column?

Comment: Thanks I cannot escape special characters because I need to decrypt the string later.

Comment: Is it possible for you to perhaps un-escape the string right before decryption? It would essentially be similar to encoding to base64 and then decoding again before decrypting